# how can i alter table in sqlite database through the obj c methods in iphone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, insert-update

hii every one

I need to add one column to my existing table so how can i alter table in sqlite database through the obj c ,i am using the following code for inserting data into table in the same way how can i write updata table method

```
- (void) InsertRecord {


if(addStmt == nil) {
    const char *sql = "insert into tbl_Users(FirstName,MiddleName) Values(?,?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [strFirstName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [strMiddleName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
//sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [strLogin UTF8String], -3, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
else
    //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
    //productID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

//Reset the add statement.
sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
```

}

can any one help me,,thanx in advance

Comment: hi, have you tried 'sqlitepersistentobjects'? https://github.com/everzet/sqlitepersistentobjects, I think it's useful to manipulate SQLite

Comment: Thats a good reason why I use CoreData which adds automatically columns depending on user schema version... Thanks to this I've never wrote a sqlite update table...

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Comment: can any one give me one simple executable testproject,i have tried that link but those codes r crashing,,thanx in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might be of some use.
Header File

```
NSString *databasePath;
```

.m File
//Make a call to these Methods

```
    [self checkAndCreateDB ];
    [self alterDB];

-(void)checkAndCreateDB {
    NSString* databaseName = @"MasterDB.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    BOOL success1;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success1 = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success1) return;
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}

-(void) alterDB{
    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ALTER TABLE User ADD COLUMN testColumn TEXT"];
        const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE) 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DB altered" message:@"Success" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];    
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert=nil;

        }
        else 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DB Updation" message:@"DB not Altered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];   
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert=nil;
        }   
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);    
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```