# sqlitedatabase table creation in ios

Tags: ios

```
 NSString *sql2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %@ (officenoId INTEGER,companyname VARCHAR(20),cellnoId INTEGER,firstname varchar(30),lastname varchar(30));",customertable];
```

error is table has two columns but four values are supplied 
please tell me the way how to add column in existing table.

Comment: Look at any SQL documentation. ALTER TABLE ADD

Comment: Refer this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828524/how-can-i-alter-table-in-sqlite-database-through-the-obj-c-methods-in-iphone-pro

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN columnname
```

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a created table, you should take a look here:

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Or here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253879/4779986

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN columnName type;
```

If you want to create a table only if It doesn't exist:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLENAME(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   COLUMN1 TEXT NOT NULL,
   COLUMN2 INT NOT NULL,
   COLUMN3 CHAR(50),
   COLUMN4 REAL
);
```